# Differential equation - looks easy but I do not find the right concept

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve find $y(x)$, which solves this equation:

$a y'(x) y(x)^n +b y'(x)+c y(x)=0$

What type of solution concept do I have to use (name of the differential equation?)? Is there a good book tutorial to look into?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just a quick comment. The type of differential equation you're looking at is a separable first order differential equation. In general, for higher order differential equations not depending explicitly on $x$, this differential equation is also autonomous. As far a book is concerned, I found Ordinary Differential Equations by Adkins and Davidson to be a good text.

Answer (score 3):

This is separable and integrates after division by $y$ to $$\frac any^n+b\ln|y|+cx=d.$$

This can be further transformed to
$$
\frac aby^n+\ln|y^n|=\frac nb(d-cx)\implies \frac aby^ne^{\frac aby^n}=De^{-\frac{nc}bx}
$$
where $D$ contains a collection of constant factors. This can now further be transformed using the Lambert-W function to
$$
\frac aby^n=W(De^{-\frac{nc}bx})
$$
etc., but several restrictions apply stemming from the domain of the Lambert-W function and

Comment: And what? :) you made me curious

Comment: Wow, this a nice approach. I did not see this. Thank you. Does this allow me to derive any insights into $y(x)$? Specifically, is it decreasing in $a$ respectively $b$? I would guess, that it is decreasing in $a$ and increasing in $b$.

Comment: Hi Lutz, I ried to reconstruct you approach. May it be the case that the step "This can be further transformed to
$$
\frac aby^n+\ln|y^n|=\frac{d-cx}b\implies \frac aby^ne^{\frac aby^n}=De^{-\frac cbx}
$$"   should result in This can be further transformed to
$$
\frac an y^n+\ln|y|=\frac{d-cx}b\implies \frac a n y e^{\frac{a}{b}y^n}=e^{-\frac cbx}
$$, or am I missing sth.?

Comment: @Paul: You are right, the multiplication with $n$ was not completed. I need the factor in front of the exponential to be the same as the exponent to match the definition of the Lambert-W function.

Comment: @Lutz: I think it is still not 100% correct.  

This can be further transformed to
$$
\frac{a}{b} y^n+\ln|y^n|=\frac nb(d-cx)\implies y^n e^{\frac aby^n}=De^{-\frac{nc}bx}
$$
where $D$ contains a collection of constant factors. By inserting $1=a/b* b/a$,
this can now further be transformed using the Lambert-W function to
$$
\frac{b}{a} y^n=W(De^{-\frac{nc}bx})
$$

Can we get a closed form solution from this Lambert-W function?

Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Lambert-W does not really count as "closed solution". It is used because it has some simple properties and several approximation algorithms. You need to establish the pattern $ue^u=v$ to then invert this to $u=W(v)$, here $u=\frac ab y^n$. If $y_0=y(0)$, then $D=\frac ab y_0^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Given equation modifies to y'(ay^n+b)=-cy
=>dy(ay^(n-1)+b/y)=-cdx
integrating we get
a(y^n)/n+b*ln(y)= -cx + C; where C is some arbitrary constant

Comment: I had this result, too. Does this allow me to derive any insights into y(x)? Specifically, is it decreasing in a respectively b?